# app_offline.htm Is Causing .net core 3.1 application to terminate

Tags: asp.net-core

I am running a .net core 3.1 web application in visual studio 2019 which terminates unexpectedly without giving any exception while running and when i see logs in windows event viewer i see there are two significant logs.
1. Application 'F:\Insignia Projects\Colaraz_Revamp\src\Services\Identity\Identity.API\' was recycled after detecting app_offline.htm.
2.Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/IDENTITY.API' has shutdown.
So I think the application termination is happening due to app_offline.htm. So please give me any suggestion about how to prevent this termination.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't add app_offline file it will not add it by default. Could you please tell me which operation you have used to add the app_offline file?

Comment: i don't have app_offline file in my project and nor i have added this file, but when my application terminates unexpectedly then i see  this log  Application 'F:\Insignia Projects\Colaraz_Revamp\src\Services\Identity\Identity.API\' was recycled after detecting app_offline.htm

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this - I have the same issue.

Comment: no the problem is still there, if you find the solution please share with me